# php-login.net is minimal ssecure enough

Tags: php

I saw some scripts at [php-login.net](http://www.php-login.net) and there is different scripts (one-file,minimal,advanced,proffesional) and I'm not very good at php to determine the difference between each of them. I'm confused between minimal and advanced, at first look at the demo I saw that "advanced" have a "keep me loged in" choice and captcha and password reset but I don't think that I'll need them in my site. what I want to ask is: Is minimal secure enough compared to advanced script?

Comment: Run them all, see which one you like and suits you best. We can't make that choice for you; *too broad*.

Comment: Maybe go here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you just trying to assess them, are you thinking of using one? How much experience do you have and for what purpose were you thinking of using one? All considerations I would make.

Comment: @Fred-ii- there is a demo for each of them at php-login.net, I have tried them and I want to know if there is a difference in security between them, I'm not good at php so I can't know what the difference.

Comment: Consult the answer below.

Comment: @Hammerstein yes depending on their security and I want to use minimal because advanced have feauters that I don't need and I want to use it as a login system for a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all secure. Difference is just their features;

One-File:

> The one file version: One PHP file plus one database file. No MySQL database needed. No need to install anything.

**Just Register/Login, Very simple, nothing special.**

Minimal:

> Simple login, logout, registration. Uses mysqli. Not more than necessary. Just the basic functions.

**Like One-file version, but uses MySQL Instead of SQLite.**

Advanced:

> The advanced version comes with a lot of features, but is still reduced to the max. Uses MySQL.

**Plus 'Keep me signed in' and 'Forgot My Password', also, uses PDO_MySQL.**

Professional:

> A real framework with lots of features, (captchas, facebook-login, local and remote avatar handling, remember-me cookies, SMTP mail sending, etc) and a clean MVC structure. Perfect for building real apps on top of it.

**No need to explain, i think.**